# NodeJS HTTP server stalled on V8 execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous, v8

**EDITED**

I have a nodeJS http server that is meant for receiving uploads from multiple clients and processing them separately.
My problem is that I've verified that the first request blocks the reception of any other request until the previous request is served.

This is the code I've tested:

```
var http = require('http');
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 200;
var url = require('url');
var instance = require('./build/Release/ret');

http.createServer( function(req, res){
    var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname; 
    console.log("<req>"+path+"</req>");
    switch (path){
        case ('/test'): 
            var body = [];
            req.on('data', function (chunk) {
                body.push(chunk);
            });
            req.on('end', function () {
                body = Buffer.concat(body);
                console.log("---req received---");
                console.log(Date.now());
                console.log("------------------");          
                instance.get(function(result){
                  postHTTP(result, res);
                });
            });
        break;
    }
}).listen(9999);
```

This is the native side (omitting obvious stuff) where getInfo is the exported method:

```
std::string ret2 (){
  sleep(1); 
  return string("{\"image\":\"1.JPG\"}");
}

Handle<Value> getInfo(const Arguments &args) {
  HandleScope scope;
  if(args.Length() == 0 || !args[0]->IsFunction())
    return ThrowException(Exception::Error(String::New("Error")));

  Persistent<Function> fn = Persistent<Function>::New(Handle<Function>::Cast(args[0]));

  Local<Value> objRet[1] = {    
    String::New(ret2().c_str())
  };
  Handle<Value> ret = fn->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 1, objRet);

  return scope.Close(Undefined());
```

}

I'm resting this with 3 curl parallel requests

```
for i in {1..3}; do time curl --request POST --data-binary "@/home/user/Pictures/129762.jpg" http://192.160.0.1:9999/test & done
```

This is the output from the server:

```
<req>/test</req>
---req received---
1397569891165
------------------
<req>/test</req>
---req received---
1397569892175
------------------
<req>/test</req>
---req received---
1397569893181
------------------
```

These the response and the timing from the client:

```
"1.JPG"
real    0m1.024s
user    0m0.004s
sys         0m0.009s
"1.JPG"
real    0m2.033s
user    0m0.000s
sys         0m0.012s
"1.JPG"
real    0m3.036s
user    0m0.013s
sys         0m0.001s
```

Apparently requests are received after the previous has been served. The sleep(1) simulates a synchronous operation that requires about 1s to complete and can't be changed.
The client receives the responses with an incremental delay of ~1s.

I would like to achieve a kind of parallelism, although I'm aware I'm in a single threaded environment such as nodeJS. What I would like to achieve is receiving all 3 answers is ~1s.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
for(var i=0;i<1000000000;i++) var a=a+i;
```

Is a pretty severe blocking operation. As soon as the first block ends. Your whole server hangs until this for loop is done. I'm interested in why you are trying to do this.

Perhaps you are trying to simulate a delayed response ?

```
setTimeout(function)({
    send404(res);
}, 3000);
```

Right now you are turning a non-flowing stream into flowing mode by attaching a `data` event handler, and  subsequently loading the whole stream into memory. You probably don't want to do this.

You can use the stream in now-flowing mode as illustrated below, this is useful if you want to send the data to some place that is only accessible after some other event.

However, using the stream in flowing mode is the fastest. If you want to write your own body parser I suppose you might want to use flowing mode, it depends on your use case.

```
req.on('readable', function () {
   var chunk;
   while (null !== (chunk = readable.read())) {
       body.push(chunk);
   }
});
```

Flowing and non-flowing mode is also know as respectively v1 and v2 streams, as the older streams used in node only supported flowing mode.

Comment: I've tried to set a timeout, but as you said it is a non-blocking operation. In my real deployment I have a blocking operation, so I thought that it would have been a good way to simulate it.
I'm not sure how can I listen to readable stream events in this case.

Comment: I would advice you to change your real deployment to remove that blocking operation, any blocking operation is close to deadly for node.js performance.

Comment: What is the blocking operation in the real deployment?  Most things in nodejs do blocking operations in the background, even if its a c module you can do things in a thread and then call the callback when the operation is finished.  You should never use the fs.[read|write]sync calls, always use the asynchronous calls.

Comment: Can't use threads cause not all libs I've linked to the node C extension are thread safe. I'm gonna try with node-ffi to see if it is any different. Can't think of anything else.

Comment: You can just spread the calculation of your blocking operation over the event loop if it is not to time sensitive. If you would share your use case we might give you some more solid feedback.

Comment: You are right I'm gonna update the question with the Cpp part that I ruled out.
In the meanwhile, I'm trying to understand if executing the rest of JS code in a callback triggered from C-side would solve the problem. Thanks for your help.